JS aggregation causes a console error
I'd like to activate the core JS aggregation but I am having an error in the console when I do it:
Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid property id
The error is triggered from d3@7.6.1.min.js which is declared as a custom library component
dataviz_utils:
  version: 1.
  js:
    ../../../../../libraries/dompurify/dist/purify.min.js: { }
    assets/js/lib/chart@3.9.1.min.js: { }
    assets/js/lib/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.1.0.min.js: { }
    assets/js/lib/d3-zoom.v1.min.js: { }
    assets/js/lib/d3@7.6.1.min.js: { }
    assets/js/lib/ResizeObserver@1.5.1.min.js: { }
    assets/js/lib/jquery.typeahead@2.11.0.min.js: { }
    assets/js/dataviz.utils.js: { }
  css:
    theme:
      assets/css/jquery.typeahead@2.11.0.min.css: { }
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery

I have no error when the aggregation is turned off. Everything works as expected.
I checked the dependencies, it looks good.
I am wondering what could cause that error...
If anyone has a clue, feel free to share it

You should mark already-minified files with minified: true in the options object. If aggregation is problematic for a library, also add preprocess: false.
